# Preventing kernel restart while training a model on tensorflow with GPU

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, gpu, nvidia

The problem:
I am trying to train a model in the following system and after a bit of training (some times 1 or 2 epochs or maybe some iterations) the provided error appears. I have tried many solutions from the web and other stack questions. Also I attached a picture of GPU status when the problem occurs.

System config:

Windows 10, Cuda: 11.2.2, Cudnn 8.1.0.77, Tensorflow 2.10.1, GPU NVIDIA GRID V100D-8Q.

What I did:

- reducing the batch size (now 2).
- config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = .n, with different n values.
- tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)

Training starts and based on the parameters continue a while, for example:

Epoch 1/200

```
16/351 [>.............................] - ETA: 3:21 - loss: 2.3901 - f1_score: 0.0000e+00 - true_positives: 0.0000e+00
```

The error Jupyter pops up:
Kernel Restarting

```
The kernel for inter_DS_no_one_hot (snorkel data).ipynb appears to have died. It will restart automatically.
```

[image]